# How to check for required radio and checkbox inputs in a form and then display a message if they're checked or unchecked?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

I implemented some user feedback for users. If required fields are empty, some error messages will appear to alert users that the inputs are empty.

I have been working all weekend on this. I get the correct feedback for empty 'text' values. I'm having a hard time checking for empty checkbox and radio inputs. By default, when you click submit/check, you get the correct error message for empty 'text' fields but not radio and checkbox items.

---

**My code:**
HTML

```
    <form id="my-form" class="form" action="/" method="post">
      <div class="form-row">
    <label for="name" class="form-label">Name *</label>
    <div class="form-field">
      <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Please enter your name" type="text" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="email" class="form-label">Email *</label>
    <div class="form-field">
      <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Please enter your email address" type="email" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="radio" class="form-label">Radio Buttons *</label>
    <div class="form-field">
      <span class="form-radios">Select 1: </span>
      <input id="radio" name="radiobutton" value="selection-one" type="radio" required>
      <span class="form-radios">Select 2: </span>
      <input name="radiobutton" value="selection-two" type="radio">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="checkbox" class="form-label">Checkboxes *</label>
    <div class="form-field">
      <span class="form-radios">Select 1: </span>
      <input id="checkbox1" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="checkbox1value" required>
      <span class="form-radios">Select 2: </span>
      <input id="checkbox2" value="checkbox2value" name="checkbox" type="checkbox">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="tel" class="form-label">Telephone *</label>
    <div class="form-field">
      <input id="tel" name="telephone" placeholder="Please enter your number" type="tel" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="website" class="form-label">Website *</label>
    <div class="form-field">
      <input id="website" name="website" placeholder="Begin with https://" type="url" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="message" class="form-label">Message *</label>
    <div class="form-field">
      <textarea id="message" name="How long were you away for?" placeholder="Include all the details you can" required></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <button id="check" name="submit" type="submit" class="form-submit">Send Email</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
const requiredElements = document.getElementById("my-form").querySelectorAll("[required]"),   
submitButton = document.getElementById("check"),
errorMsgOutput = document.getElementById("output");


submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
var errorMsg = "";
var radios = document.getElementById("my-form").radiobutton;
var checboxes = document.getElementById("my-form").checbox;

  for (var i = 0; i < requiredElements.length; i++) {
    var form = requiredElements[i];

    // Checking for empty text fields
        if (form.value.length) {
                errorMsg += form.name + ": " + "Filled" + "<br>";
            } else if (form.value.length === 0) {
                errorMsg += form.name + ": " + "Not Filled" + "<br>";
            }

            // My attempt to check that radio values are filled. By default, the error message says that it's checked ('filled') even when it's not.

            // for(var j = 0, k = radios.length; j < k; j++){
            //  if (form.type == 'radio' && radios[k].checked) {
      //       errorMsg += form.name + ": " + "Filled" + "<br>";
      //   } else {
      //       errorMsg += form.name + ": " + "Not Filled" + "<br>";
      //   }
            // }
    }
    errorMsgOutput.innerHTML = errorMsg;
});
```

Even before you click the send email button, the checkbox and radio inputs display the 'filled' error message.  See: https://jsfiddle.net/krisixco/zgdf2sec/10/ to see what I mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < requiredElements.length; i++) {
    var form = requiredElements[i];

    // Checking for empty text fields
    if(form.name === "radiobutton" || form.name === "checkbox" ){
      if(!form.checked) errorMsg += form.name + ": " + "Not Filled" + "<br>";
      if(form.checked) errorMsg += form.name + ": " + "Filled" + "<br>";


    } else{
    if (form.value.length) {


                errorMsg += form.name + ": " + "Filled" + "<br>";
            } else if (form.value.length === 0) {
                errorMsg += form.name + ": " + "Not Filled" + "<br>";
            }
    }
```

Comment: @Arog Lith i have updated your Js fiddle file https://jsfiddle.net/c9qxo32L/12/ ,

Comment: Woww....really...smh! This works Shabeeb! Thank you. I appreciate it.

Comment: @ArgoLith welcome, make this answer as answered by clicking the tick sign, highly appreciated

Comment: Hi shabeeb. Quick question. How would I do the exact thing with a select input. See the code you edited here with the select input test. https://jsfiddle.net/vac4q9wy/

Comment: @ArgoLith 
<select id="test" name="selectinput" class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect04" aria-label="Example select with button addon" required>

    <option  value="">Choose...</option>

    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>

Comment: I know how to add the select. I'm asking how would I check for it as well? It says filled automatically when it should say 'not filled' if the value hasn't been entered.

Comment: copy above select tag code and replace with existing select tag code, it will work,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212581/discussion-between-shabeeb-ck-and-argo-lith).

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you ask two questions. The first is why the required does not display a pop-up for radio and checkbox and the second is how to check if they were filled in or not by javascript.

About the first question, in the code you put in your question, the checkbox and radio inputs do not have the required attribute

For the second question use the checked method

example:

```js
let checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]')

if(checkbox.checked){
  // checked
else {
  // not checked
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Aks! Appreciate it!